# How to detect support for the HTML5 "download" attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

One of the new features implemented in HTML5 is the `download` attribute for anchor tags. The benefit of this attribute is that it gives users the means to download content created within a client application, such as an image (converted from a canvas, for instance).

Currently, support for this feature is very poor, so I'd like to know how can I detect support for this feature in a browser.

Comment: For anyone who's wondering, this feature is strongly supported as of 2022: https://caniuse.com/?search=download%20attribute%20a

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use the [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/a/download.js) approach: create the element, and check if the attribute is defined:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
if (typeof a.download != "undefined") {
    alert('has support');
}
```

Comment: Or the short version `var downloadAttrSupported = ("download" in document.createElement("a"))`

Comment: I suggested including Modernizr itself, but this might indeed be better if it's for one single usecase.

Comment: @AndreiOniga thanks for the suggestion, I updated my answer.  Maybe *(typeof a.download == 'string')* would be safer still?

Comment: @dbaseman Actually, "undefined" is the standard implementation. Anything else isn't, to my knowledge, so checking whether "(typeof X == 'undefined')" or not is the way to go. Anyway, many thanks for the answer! It solved my problem :)

Comment: This solution appears to not work anymore; modern versions of Firefox seem to have the `a.download` defined, but doesn't use it.

Comment: @MidnightLightning which version are you referring to?  I just checked Firefox 26, and it still shows `a.download` as `undefined`.  Then again, this page claims that version 20 *does* have support, but but only for same-origin links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/20?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Firefox_20_for_developers

Comment: @McGarnagle: using the console in Firefox 26 to do `document.createElement('a').target` returns an empty string on my Mac, not 'undefined'. I'm trying to download a data URL, so that probably doesn't fall under the "same-origin" umbrella...

Comment: @MidnightLightning You do mean `document.createElement('a').download`, right? `target` should always return an empty string.

Comment: Whoops, right... `document.createElement('a').download` is an empty string too on Firefox 26 on my Mac!

Answer (score 1):

A single-line `if` condition to keep things simplified:

```
if (document.createElement('a').download==undefined && e.target.hasAttribute('download'))
{
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log('Error: this is a download link, please right-click to save the file.');
}
```

Support for the `download` attribute is spotty (Chrome 14+, Firefox 20+, IE13+, Safari 10+ and no support in (real) Opera. The script above will not interfere with supported browsers.