# force browser to download large file from external server

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am trying to download and rename a file (about 3-4GB) from external server, but I don't want to copy file on my web server and then send to browser, because it takes too much time.

I tried this

```
<a class="downloads" download="SomeName.m4v" href="http://Externalserver/file.m4v">Download!</a>
```

but it works only in Google Chrome.

Is there some way to do something like this?

Comment: What happens when you click in another browser? Did you try the "Save As"?

Comment: In other browsers downloaded filename is an original filename

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to *rename* a file on a server by clicking on a link on a webpage? This doesn't make any sense to me (despite the obvious fact that this cannot possibly work). The code you posted will tell a browser that understands HTML5 to download a file from another server (i.e. _not_ attempt to display it), but that's it. A broser _might_ offer you to choose a local filename (and destination) at its discretion, or it might not. But that's something different.

Comment: I agree with @Damon, are you worried just about the name of the file?

Comment: no i want to download "http://Externalserver/file.m4v" as "SomeName.m4v"

Comment: So you just want to rename the file. And It wont be possible to force the user for name. You just can suggest it as @Damon said.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12112844/266919