# Export ng-Grid to csv not working in IE

Tags: angular-ui, export-to-csv, ng-grid

Tried to implement **export ng-grid to csv** functionality using the ng-grid-csv-export plugin. But it did not work for IE.
Next, followed this [blog](http://jessemon.blogspot.com/2013/11/download-data-from-angular-nggrid-as-csv.html). It uses **node.js on server** to return csv from webservice, however, we **don't** have access there.

Then followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683995/how-to-inject-http-service-into-the-ng-grid-csv-export-plugin) post to implement the form action for IE. However, this does not work as **downloadCsv** function is not getting called.

Please let me know if I'm missing out on something and request you to please post an **example** of a URL which accepts a POST request with JSON encoded object in the payload and return a CSV.

Comment: facing same issue in IE. http://plnkr.co/edit/PUetI8JOF6gkwFKoV303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support the data URI link.

I got around the issue by detecting IE and falling back to an `iFrame` solution and using `document.execCommand`

Details can be found here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26003382/378151