# Download button

Tags: javascript, download

I am making an audio player, and I would like to include a button that downloads the current track. I have tried the common solutions people suggest, but these only open the .mp3 in a new tab and play it. This is what I am using:

```
document.getElementById("dlButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
window.location = "tracks/CFKZ.mp3";});
```

I saw another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript/) on stack overflow:

```
<form method="get" action="file.doc">
<button type="submit">Download!</button>
</form>
```

I don't understand this. It doesn't make sense to me why a download button would need to send information to the file that is to be downloaded.

Comment: Clyde , what is dlButton on your post?

Comment: Why don't you just make a link?

Comment: try this [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library

Comment: @JaromandaX: That's not what he wants.

Comment: @SLaks so, he doesn't want a button to download the file rather than play it? I must've misread the question, I'll leave it in your culpable hands then, champ

Comment: @NagaSaiA: dlButton is `<img id="dlButton" src="download.svg">`
@SLaks: the link opens the file in a new tab with the browser's default media player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 solution with a simple anchor tag using the 'download' attribute (doesn't require any javascript):

```
<a href="/music/somefile.mp3" download="somefile.mp3">Download mp3</a>
```

the download attribute can also be used to rename the file:

```
<a href ="/music/3ri3nlfkndfoiweuio.mp3" download="TheManWhoSoldTheWorld.mp3" >Download a Bowie Hit</a>
```

will download as 'TheManWhoSoldTheWorld.mp3'

**edit for cross browser support (relies on Modernizr - which you should use if worried about cross-browser support https://modernizr.com/):**

maybe this fiddle will help: https://jsfiddle.net/abigwonderful/3jfqz5j0/2/
or just open this window in multiple browsers and click 'Run code snippet' below:

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
if (typeof a.download == "undefined") {
    //append some text to inform the user 
    //they should right-click the link to download
    //example:
    var downloadDiv = document.getElementById('download');
    downloadDiv.innerHTML = "Right-click the link and select 'Save as...' to download the mp3";

}
```

```html
<a href="/music/somefile.mp3" download="somefile.mp3">Download mp3</a>
<div id="download"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not supported cross-browser

Comment: @Clyde are you using Modernizer?

Comment: @Clyde Midernizr would allow you to see if the user's browser supports the download attribute. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112844/how-to-detect-support-for-the-html5-download-attribute

Comment: @LucasWatson but what to do for the browsers that don't support it?

Comment: @Clyde if you look at the code example above, there is a conditional that runs if the browser doesn't support it. This conditional adds some text that instructs the user how to click/save the linked file.

Comment: @Clyde the alternative solution is altering server side setup. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @Clyde For Safari and IE, there is no straightforward solution. You'll have to look into using JS along with iframes to get that working.

Comment: @Clyde click on the jsfiddle link in my answer. open that link in multiple browsers. Does that help?

Comment: these suggestions point me in the right direction. I am willing to learn about iframes and server-side setup, provided that the latter can be done even if i am using a shared host. Otherwise I will use the Modernizr solution. What kind of server-side setup? Thank you both

Comment: @Clyde what kind of server are you running on?

Comment: @abigwonderful the jsfiddle helps! I will be able to work with this. I am using a shared server, Linux I believe.

Comment: @Clyde great! Sounds like maybe an apache server. Do you have access to an .htaccess file?

Comment: @abigwonderful i'm sorry I can't give reputation yet ... I have cPanel if that is what you were asking? In the root I don't see an .htaccess file (hidden files are shown)

Comment: @Clyde Have a look at this link - it's targeted at Drupal users, but is a pretty easy to follow set of instructions. You'll want to specify <FilesMatch "\.(?i:mp3)$"> to make sure it targets .mp3 files. Let me know if this works and I'll update my answer as well. https://www.drupal.org/node/417866

Comment: @abigwonderful It turns out I have an nginx server. Is the process a whole lot different with nginx? Meantime I will get to work on your other solution using Modernizr.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice for download links is the following:

```
<a href="path/to/file" class="button" download>Some text</a>
```

This is fairly well supported cross-browser. You can style the link with a class to make it look like a button, perhaps with something like the following:

```
.button {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Edit: If you want to use this and have it work in Safari or IE, look into using something like Modernizr.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code and see whether it is what you want

```
<a href="test.zip" download='test'><input type="button" value="Download Now"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

How bout using an anchor tag, just use bootstrap to make it look like a button.

```
 <a href="tracks/CFKZ.mp3" download="tracks/CFKZ.mp3">Download!</a>
```

Comment: This opens CFKZ.mp3 in a new tab and plays it with the browser's default audio player, but does not download it.

Comment: try the download attritute. please see code edit above.